# SQLite is creating a disk file for In-memory DB

Tags: c#, sqlite

I tried to create a shareable in-memory database as per the documentation provided on SQLite Site. But I end up finding the solution to the problem.

```
 var connectionString = "Data Source=sharedmemdb;Mode=Memory;Cache=Shared";

            using (var connection1 = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection1.Open();

                var command1 = connection1.CreateCommand();
                command1.CommandText =
                    "CREATE TABLE Message ( Text TEXT );" +
                    "INSERT INTO Message ( Text ) VALUES ( 'Is there anybody out there?' );";
                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                using (var connection2 = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection2.Open();

                    var command2 = connection2.CreateCommand();
                    command2.CommandText = "SELECT Text FROM Message;";


                    var message = command2.ExecuteScalar() as string;
                }
            }
```

If I execute this code, it will create in-memory DB named as sharedmemdb and shared cache is enabled while making the connection, so this connection accessible to other connections also. If I run this first time this works pretty fine but if I close the application and run again it throws error "Table Message already exists" and this looks very strange as I created the table in-memory and this should not be available if application restarts.

After getting this error, I looked into the application directory and found the file "sharedmemdb" which means SQLite is not creating the shareable in-memory DB.

Any clue why this is happening?

**After moving command to `using` block:**

```
var connectionString = "Data Source =sharedmemdb; Mode = Memory; Cache = Shared";

            using (var connection1 = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection1.Open();

                using (var command1 = connection1.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command1.CommandText =
                        "CREATE TABLE Message ( Text TEXT );" +
                        "INSERT INTO Message ( Text ) VALUES ( 'Is there anybody out there?' );";
                    command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                using (var connection2 = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection2.Open();

                    using (var command2 = connection2.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        command2.CommandText = "SELECT Text FROM Message;";


                        var message = command2.ExecuteScalar() as string;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no connection remaining?

Comment: Yes.no connection remaining

Comment: I can reproduce this issue. But I have no clue why

Comment: I couldn't find any evidence that the C# SQLite connection string supports the mode parameter (SQLite itself certainly does, but who knows what the Microsoft version is doing). If you just need a single shared in-memory database you can just connect to :memory: instead.

Comment: @Cubic. Thanks. but I want this to be shareable by other connections.

Comment: Is there any other way like, To create connection object globally and use it everywhere in the application?

Comment: Does it help if you use `using` with your `Command` objects?

Comment: I have not tried that. Let me check. Did you tested that?

Comment: Question updated. check now

Comment: Ok, what library/version are you using? I can't reproduce this with Microsoft.Data.Sqlite v2.0.1.

All that being said, you should probably evaluate if you really need a shared memory DB. SQLite isn't made for concurrent writes (though it has reasonable handling for concurrent reads, but it's not built for handling concurrent writes. Also, a named in-memory DB still disappears if you lose all connections to it, so it's not really suitable for a messy model where you open and close connections all over the place.

Comment: I am using `system.data.sqlite`

Comment: Thanks, @Cubic. I tried `using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;` and its working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

System.Data.SQLite doesn't support the "Mode" parameter (that's Microsoft.Data.Sqlite).

However, in System.Data.SQLite you can use the "FullUri" parameter to pass arguments directly to SQLite, so you can achieve what you wanted by changing your connection string to

```
FullUri=file:mem.db?mode=memory&cache=shared
Protocol^    ^      ^           ^
DB Name -----|      |           |
Use memory mode ----+           |
Use shared cache ---------------+
```

(The first line being the actual connection string, the next couple of lines breaking it down)

Comment: Did you tested `FullUri=file:mem.db?mode=memory&cache=shared` with `System.Data.SQLite` namespace?

Comment: Can you give some example with `System.Data.SQLite`